# Error - the platform "linux" is incompatible with fsevents - after upgrading to laravel-mix 4.0.14

Tags: ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg, laravel-mix, fsevents

After upgrading to laravel-mix 4.0.14, I'm running

```
yarn check
```

And I'm getting:

> yarn check v1.13.0
>
> error fsevents@1.2.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
>
> error Found incompatible module

As I can see fsevents is a package regarding Mac OSX, but I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

I have:

> "fsevents": "^1.2.4",

In dependencies in package.json

NPM version: 6.7.0

Node version: 11.9.0

How can I get a rid of this?

If I downgrade to v.2.1.14 this error is gone but I'm getting audit alert

Comment: Known bug. Context: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2051